# Encoding Categorical Data

Tags: categorical-data

I am trying to predict a car price from a given dataset. When I am trying to encode the categorical data I am getting an error. I am attaching an image with the error below. Can someone help me know what I am doing wrong ? I am new to this domain.
Above this code block I imported libraries and dataset and divided it into X and y.
[image]

Comment: I don't see any image attached.  Perhaps just paste the error text into a code block?  You can enter "Code Sample" mode by pressing Ctrl + K

Comment: Sorry, attached the file now

Comment: Seems X.shape has just one element. Could you print X

Comment: I printed X, and it works fine... It has multiple features and all print correctly.

Comment: Initial X.shape output is (10781, 8)
After the column transformation, X.shape gives the output (10781, 37)
But when I try use np.array on the column transformer output, the dimension gets ()
zero dimension array